# How to combine a list with a number sequence in r?

Tags: r, list, web-scraping

I am doing my PhD research on the online forums dedicated to WW2. I have a question which seems very basic to me, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

There's a list of links where the links only differ by author_ids. Like this:

```
[1] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start="  
[2] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=4&start="  
[3] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=6&start="  
[4] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=7&start="  
[5] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=8&start="  
[6] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=9&start="  
[7] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=10&start=" 
[8] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=11&start=" 
[9] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=12&start=" 
[10] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=13&start="
# etc until id=111
```

Then I have a sequence of numbers from 0 to 17000 by 15 that looks like this:

```
 [1]     0    15    30    45    60    75    90   105   120   135   150  165   180   195   210   225   240   255
 [19]   270   285   300   315   330   345   360   375   390   405   420   435   450   465   480   495   510   525
 [37]   540   555   570   585   600   615   630   645   660   675   690   705   720   735   750   765   780   795
 [55]   810   825   840   855   870   885   900   915   930   945   960   975   990  1005  1020  1035  1050  1065
  # etc until 17000
```

I want to create link lists where the link with each id number correlates with each element from the sequence of numbers. Here's the example of it for id=2:

```
[1] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start=0"    
[2] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start=15"   
[3] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start=30"   
[4] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start=45"   
[5] "http://forum.axishistory.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&author_id=2&start=60"
```

I guess you get the idea. 
I was trying to write a for loop:

```
for (i in 100) {
  paste0(links_p1[[i]], no)
}
```

but it only puts out the list for the 100th element.

When I tried the lapply function, the output was that paste0 isn't a function.

The best I have so far is this:

```
links_max_1 <- paste0(links_p1[[1]], no)
links_max_2 <- paste0(links_p1[[2]], no)
links_max_3 <- paste0(links_p1[[3]], no)
links_max_4 <- paste0(links_p1[[4]], no)
links_max_5 <- paste0(links_p1[[5]], no)
# etc until links_max_100
```

and this is obviously not very good. How can I put together the numbers with each of the elements of the links_p1 list?

Comment: `for (i in 100)` asks for the computer to process an `i` for each element in the vector `100`. What is the vector `100`? It's a **scalar** ie a vector of length 1. You only get one result because you have only requested one result... `for (i in 1:100)` looks through the vector `seq(1, 100, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this.  Here's some sample data to start with.

```
urls <- c("abc", "def")
nums <- 1:5
```

---

**Option 1:** Take advantage of recycling in `paste()`.  This will return an atomic vector with all the authors in order, but mixed in the same vector.

```
paste0(rep(urls, each = length(nums)), nums)
# [1] "abc1" "abc2" "abc3" "abc4" "abc5" "def1" "def2" "def3" "def4" "def5"
```

---

**Option 2:** Use `lapply()`.  This may be preferred if you want to keep authors separate. Each list element contains all the urls for one author.

```
lapply(urls, paste0, nums)
# [[1]]
# [1] "abc1" "abc2" "abc3" "abc4" "abc5"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "def1" "def2" "def3" "def4" "def5"
```

---

**Option 3**: Fix the `for()` loop.  To fix your `for()` loop, you need to allocate a result vector and assign to it in the loop.

```
out <- vector("list", length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(out)) {
    out[[i]] <- paste0(urls[i], nums)
}
```

And now we have `out` as a new object, with contents

```
out
# [[1]]
# [1] "abc1" "abc2" "abc3" "abc4" "abc5"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "def1" "def2" "def3" "def4" "def5"
```